# Use SWIG to apply multiple Java data types for same C data type

Tags: swig

I have two C functions that I'm exposing through SWIG to my Java layer and both have an input param with a const void * data type ("val) that needs to be a uint8_t for the addCategory function but a char for the addAttribute function. I'm currently, in the SWIG Interface file, using the %apply to map the const void * C type to a short on the Java side. Is there a way to modify the SWIG interface file to support both a char (String) and a uint8_t (short) for the const void * input parameter?

C Functions from header file:

```
int
addCategory(query_t *query, type_t type, const void *val);

int
addAttribute(query_t *query, type_t type, const void *val);
```

SWIG Interface File:

```
%module Example
%include "stdint.i"
void setPhy_idx(uint32_t value);
%include "arrays_java.i"
void setId(unsigned char *value);
%{
#include "Example.h"
%}
%apply char * { unsigned char * };
%apply char * { void * };
%apply uint8_t { const void * }
%apply int32_t { int32_t * }
%include "Example.h"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly do this - what type would be used in this place in Java? You need to help SWIG decide that in some way.

You have (at least) three possible solutions:

1. Use a type hierarchy - The base type will be what the function takes, the subclasses will get wrapped also. You could do this on the C++ side, or on the Java side using SWIG's typemap facilities. I think this is needlessly complicated though, so I've not made an example here.
2. Use overloads (or even different functions, with different names altogether - you could use `%rename` to make them back into overloads in Java even if they have different names in C)
3. Use a `union`. This will get wrapped with `set` and `get` functions by SWIG:

   ```
   %module test

   union values {
     unsigned char *string;
     void *generic;
     uint8_t someOtherThing;
     uint32_t number;
   };

   void func(values v);
   ```

   This results in a Java class called `values`, which `func()` takes and can pass one of the members of the union through. Clearly you'd want to `%apply` appropriate typemaps for the members of the `union`.